# How to get request header in Apache customized basic auth program

Tags: apache, authentication

I have used apache basic authentication, by defining "AuthExternal" and "DefineExternalAuth"(with pipe), I can successfully use the apache's basic auth with my own external program.

The question is, in my external program, is it possible to get http header info (especially customized header)?

Need to successfully get http request info in the external program which is used as apache basic auth.